# Как сделать вот такой "уголок" как в примере?

Tags: java, android

Вот есть такой дизайн

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красным квадратом выделил уголок который нужно как то нарисовать

Вопрос

Как это сделать?

Comment: Думаю, его не рисовали, а он был. Просто на исходную картинку нарисовали эту белую рамку, в которой отсутствовал тот уголок

Comment: @gil9red мне кажется это похоже на костыль

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать кастомную вьюху с отрисовкой Bitmap. В ней сделать Path любой формы. И уже через нее "смотреть" на изображение. Поереопределяем метод onDraw() в котором располагаем фигуру через которую "увидим" bitmap:

```
     canvas.clipPath(path);
```

Перед этим создадим фигуру. Метод moveTo() - начало, lineTo() - продолжение и close() - замыкание.

```
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(20,20);
    path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth()-20,20);
    path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth()-20,40);
    path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth()-5,50);
    path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth()-20,60);
    path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth()-20,canvas.getHeight()-20);
    path.lineTo(20,canvas.getHeight()-20);
    path.close();
```

"Сгенерировали" фигуру, через которую будем смотреть на изображение. Здесь я попытался "на глаз" сделать что вам надо учитывая размеры канвы. Важно помнить, что зная координаты точек, вы можете построить любую фигуру. И рисуем на канве bitmap. Матрица нужна для "подгонки" под параметры вьюхи.

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,matrix,null);
```

.

Comment: Поправьте пожалуйста свой ответ :) Конец очень путает

Comment: Поправил, надеюсь теперь понятно. Про это подробней тут https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/326-urok-148-risovanie-canvas-clip.html

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть два варианта:

1. Вы просто берете у дизайнера эту картинку(вместе с уголком) и помещаете эту картинку в ImageView
2. Вы рисуете на Canvas ( в несколько раз сложнее и дольше)

Я бы посоветовал 1 вариант.

Статьи по Canvas:

https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/311-urok-141-risovanie-dostup-k-canvas.html

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/simplepaint.php

Comment: 1) Картинки я получаю динамически 2) как?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko добавил статьи